# $.getJson function not appending to div

Tags: jquery, html, json, getjson

So I'm trying to get .json data from a JSON file provided to me, loop through it, create a div each time and append that data to it.

So far I have this function:

```
    $.getJSON( "https://api.myjson.com/bins/14uau1", function(data) {
    var dealers = data.dealers.map(dealer => {
    let currentDealer = dealer.data;
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.setAttribute("id", currentDealer.customerID);
    return newDiv.innerHTML= currentDealer;
   })

   dealers.map(i => {
     let holder = document.getElementById("dealer");
     holder.appendChild(i);
      console.log(i);
  })
```

However, whenever I try to run it, it gives me this error

```
index:212 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on   'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node
```

I realize this means that it's getting an object which is not considered an HTML element so it can't be appended into the div via .innerHTML.

So what would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there are a couple of syntax errors in your code.

There's a missing `})` which you'd want to take care of.

`return newDiv.innerHTML = currentDealer`
This line returns an assignment and not the `newDiv` like you might have intended. Instead you should assign the innerHTML first ( `newDiv.innerHTML = <value>` ) before returning the element ( `return newDiv` ). This is where you're getting your `uncaught TypeError` error.

You're also assigning a Javascript Object (`currentDealer`) to the innerHTML instead of a String. If you want to output the JSON string of this object, use `JSON.stringify`. Otherwise, make sure you are assigning the actual field you want, e.g. `currentDealer.data.companyID`.

Take note also that on this line `newDiv.setAttribute("id", currentDealer.customerID);`, you're trying to assign `currentDealer.customerID` which is an undefined value.

**So in summary**

1. First, check for syntax errors
2. Then, check that the values you are assigning exist (`console.log` & `console.dir` are your friends) and match the [data type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) you're trying to assign to

Here's a working demo:
https://codepen.io/hydrospell/pen/KvRgvB

Comment: This is super helpful and such a lifesaver! Thank you so much! It's late here but I'll study this more in the morning.